# Yii excel file is not readable

Tags: php, excel, yii

I need to import the information of an excel file into my database, but I can't make it work, here is some code I am using.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.*');
        require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
        if(!empty($_POST))
        {
            $uploadedFile=$_POST['file'];
            $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($uploadedFile);

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) 
            {
              for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) 
              {
                $content = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];

              }
            }
        }
```

**FORM IN THE VIEW:**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'excel-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'action'=>array( '/ZfPersonal/Importar' ),
        )); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::fileField('file','file'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Importar'); ?>
```

The error is

```
The filename example.xls is not readable.
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
$file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($_POST['file']);
            $path = $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'\..\bolsa\\'.$file);
            $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($path);
```

**ERROR:**

```
Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object
```

Comment: Did you check what has been sent in the http request?

Comment: if I echo $_POST['file']; It prints example.xls, but I think the problem is in the form or how I get that file.

Comment: You shouldn't get 'example.xls', since you are upploading the file you should see some binary data transiting in your http request.

Comment: And when you are using this line $file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file'); (so whitout the POST) what do you have in your yii logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `$_POST['file']` does it contain the uploaded file or the path to the file?

- If this is the uploaded file you should save the file on your server before using it in `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader`.

Example:

```
$file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
if($file !== null) {
    $file->saveAs('path/to/localFile');
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader('path/to/localFile');
} else {
    //The file hasn't been loaded
}
```

- If this is a local path to the file that you are giving then you should check permissions of this file:

Example :

```
var_dump(fileperms($_POST['file']));
```

And if needed change its permissions

```
chmod($_POST['file'], 0644);
```

Comment: $file=CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($_POST['file']); is not good, you should just pass 'file' to the method. Then getInstanceByName can return null if the file hasn't been found, I edited my post

Comment: ok, the file is null, so the Cuploaded is not working properly